# Under Up Arrow Text

Tags: arrows

I'm trying to do something similar to `$\underleftarrow{A}$`; however with the up arrow, not left or right arrows, i.e., I want to draw a pointer at `A`. Any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Will

```
\newcommand*{\underuparrow}[1]{\underset{\uparrow}{#1}}
$\underuparrow{A}$
```

help?

You can get rid of using `$` also by using `\ensuremath`:

```
\newcommand*{\underuparrow}[1]{\ensuremath{\underset{\uparrow}{#1}}}
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\underuparrow}[1]{\ensuremath{\underset{\uparrow}{#1}}}
\underuparrow{A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** You can add some coloring to spice things up:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\underuparrow}[1]{\ensuremath{\underset{\color{red}{\uparrow}}{#1}}}
\underuparrow{A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, many thanks, Will! Now, I also learn that we can add stuffs under other texts using `underset`

Comment: @ewind: Welcome.

Comment: How can you add a comment of text underneath the arrow?